# jQuery function goes away after state change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery's transfer() to move images to a center picture frame when the user hovers their mouse on the image. Here's what's supposed to happen:

1. User hovers their mouse on a thumbnail.
2. Thumbnail transfers to a picture frame in center of page.
3. Thumbnail disappears.
4. User hovers on a second thumbnail.
5. This thumbnail replaces other picture in the center frame, AND the first thumbnail reappears.
6. User hovers on first thumbnail again.
7. repeat steps 2-3.

All of steps 1-5 work in my code, which you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtNHx/). Step 6-7 are not working. It's as if the transfer code is being removed from the image by steps 2 & 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are using `one` method to bind the event. I have fixed it take a look at this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UtNHx/1/)

**Code**

```
var imgPath = new Object;
imgPath["gen"] = "http://techfeed.net/dyany.com/images/genealogyLarge.png";
imgPath["bo"] = "http://techfeed.net/dyany.com/images/BabyBoSayingOLarge.png";
var lastImage = "";
var transferInProgress = false;
$(function() {

    function runTransfer(imgID) {
        if(transferInProgress)
            return;
        transferInProgress  = true;
        var options = { to: "#picFrame", className: "ui-effects-transfer" };

        // run the transfer
        $("#"+imgID).effect("transfer", options, 1000, afterTransfer(imgID));
    };

    function afterTransfer(imgID) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#picFrame").html('<img src="'+imgPath[imgID]+'">');
            $("#"+imgID).hide();
            if ((lastImage != "") && (lastImage != imgID)) {
                $("#"+lastImage).show();
            }
            lastImage = imgID;
            transferInProgress = false;
        }, 1000);
    };

    $("#gen, #bo").mouseover(function(){runTransfer(this.id); return false; });
});
```

Comment: you could also just use .mouseover with the additional transferInProgress code

Comment: Yes, optimized it little more thanks. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UtNHx/2/)

Comment: Jake - Please mark it as an answer once you verify it, thanks.

Comment: I tried to, but I have to wait 2 minutes. I'll mark it as soon as I can though!